# Discard values while inserting and updating data using slick

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I am using `slick` with play2.
I have multiple fields in the database which are managed by the database. I don't want to create or update them, however I want to get them while reading the values.

For example, suppose I have

`case class MappedDummyTable(id: Int, .. 20 other fields, modified_time: Optional[Timestamp])`

which maps `Dummy` in the database. `modified_time` is managed by the database.

The problem is during `insert` or `update`, I create an instance of `MappedDummyTable` without the modified time attribute and pass it to slick for create/update like

`TableQuery[MappedDummyTable].insert(instanceOfMappedDummyTable)`

For this, Slick creates query as

```
Insert INTO MappedDummyTable(id,....,modified_time) Values(1,....,null)
```

and updates the modified_time as NULL, which I don't want. I want Slick to ignore the fields while updating and creating.

For updating, I can do

`TableQuery[MappedDummyTable].map(fieldsToBeUpdated).update(values)`

but this leads to 20 odd fields in the `map` method which looks ugly.

Is there any better way?

Update:

The best solution that I found was using multiple projection. I created one projection to get the values and another to update and insert the data

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to write some triggers in table if you don't want to write code like `row => (row.id,...other 20 fields)`

or try use `None` instead of `null`?

Comment: None gets converted to null by slick

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the solution with mapping non-default field is the only way to do it with Slick. To make it less ugly you can define function ignoreDefaults on MappedDummyTable that will return only non default value and function in companion object to MappedDummyTable case class that returns projection

```
TableQuery[MappedDummyTable].map(MappedDummyTable.ignoreDefaults).insert(instanceOfMappedDummyTable.ignoreDefaults)
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I have multiple columns with default values. When I pass some values for those, will they be ignored?