# Using multiple projection in slick for the same table

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I have a user table for which I will like to have multiple projections. For example, Can I have something like

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table [User] (tag, "user") {
def * = (id.?, emailId, firstName, lastName, gender) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
def allDetails = (id.?, emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, createdTime, modifiedTime)
...
}
```

I searched on Google but could not find anything. Can somebody tell me how can I use allDetails?

I will like to do

```
object Users  {
  val users = TableQuery[Users]
  def getAllDetails = ??? // How can I use allDetails here
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
   class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserInfo](tag, "user") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def emailId = column[String]("email_id", O.NotNull)
    def firstName = column[String]("firstname")
    def lastName = column[String]("lastname")
    def gender = column[String]("gender")
    def createdTime = column[Option[Timestamp]]("created_time")
    def modifiedTime = column[Option[Timestamp]]("modified_time")
    def userInfo = (emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, createdTime, modifiedTime, id.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

     def * = (emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, id.?) <> (UserInfo.tupled, UserInfo.unapply)
```

}

```
 case class User(emailId: String,
   firstName: String, lastName: String, gender: String, 
   createdTime: Option[Timestamp],    
   modifiedTime: Option[Timestamp], id: Option[Int] = None)

 case class UserInfo(emailId: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, 
      gender: String, id: Option[Int] = None)
```

**for extra projection:**

```
  val userTable = TableQuery[UserTable]

 def insert(userInfo: UserInfo) (implicit session: Session): Int = {
   //return auto incremeted id
  userTable returning (userTable.map(_.id)) += userInfo

  }

 def update(userInfo: UserInfo)(implicit session: Session) = {
   userTable.filter(_.id === userInfo.id).update(userInfo)
 }
 def getUserInfo()(implicit session: Session): List[UserInfo] = {
  userTable.list

  }
```

Comment: I don't want to have created and modified time in the default projection. By having created and modified time in default projection, slick updates the time for update queries which I want to avoid. I have posted another question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910943/discard-values-while-inserting-and-updating-data-using-slick

Comment: ok, you need to change Table[User] by Table[UserInfo] and 
def userInfo = (emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, createdTime, modifiedTime, id.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

    def * = (emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, id.?) <> (UserInfo.tupled, UserInfo.unapply)

Comment: @mohit just make sure you are not doing ddl on this table.If you are creating table by ddl.create on this userTable object.It does not create createdTime and modifiedTime columns.

Comment: "slick updates the time for update queries which I want to avoid."         
slick provide full control on update query.If you want update single column slick would update only single column not whole row.

Comment: Wait a second, how do you do insert/update/getUserInfo with a User object instead?

Comment: Yep, you said how to add it, but never, how to use it

Answer (score 8):

Had the same need recently, and started to use something like that:

```
abstract class AnyUserTable[T](tag: Tag) extends Table[T](tag, "user") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def emailId = column[String]("email_id")
    def firstName = column[String]("firstname")
    def lastName = column[String]("lastname")
    def gender = column[String]("gender")
}

class Users(tag: Tag) extends AnyUserTable[User](tag) {
    def * = (emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, id.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

class UserDetails(tag: Tag) extends AnyUserTable[UserDetail](tag) {
    def createdTime = column[Option[Timestamp]]("created_time")
    def modifiedTime = column[Option[Timestamp]]("modified_time")
    def * = (emailId, firstName, lastName, gender, createdTime, modifiedTime, id.?) <> (UserDetail.tupled, UserDetail.unapply)
}

object Users  {
    val users = TableQuery[Users]
    val getAllDetails = TableQuery[UserDetails] // That is how I propose to get all the details
}
```

borrowing the case classes from Sky's answer.

```
case class User(
    emailId: String, firstName: String, lastName: String,
    gender: String, id: Option[Int] = None)

case class UserDetail(
    emailId: String,
    firstName: String, lastName: String, gender: String,
    createdTime: Option[Timestamp],
    modifiedTime: Option[Timestamp], id: Option[Int] = None)
```

I guess that is pretty close from what I would be tempted to do using updatable views in straight sql.